# TYPO3 - Extending Site Configuration GUI with settings and imports

Tags: import, configuration, yaml, typo3, typo3-11.x

**2 questions in 1**: on a multisite TYPO3 v11 installation, I'd like to extend the TYPO3 Site Configuration GUI (for administrators who don't have SSH access to modify manually the /config.yaml files) with something like:

```
settings:
  foo1: bar1
  foo2: bar2
```

As well, I want to add by default, when config.yaml file is created, some common contents at the end of the file (i.e. news url rewriting) as "imports" like:

```
imports:
  - { resource: "<path-to-imported-yaml-file>" }
```

For now, I've only managed to extend the Site Configuration GUI, as described in the TYPO3 Doc, to have something like:

```
foo1: bar1
foo2: bar2
```

But I need the **settings** top level in order to access this values in TypoScript: {$foo1},{$foo2}...

For the imports, I didn't manage anything ...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question on how to access your custom site configuration via TypoScript:

That's possible without it being nested into a `settings` (or other) keyword. You can access your custom key e.g. like this:

```
data = site:foo1
```

See the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInTypoScript.html) for details.

The second part of your question is not so easy to answer. There is no option out of the box to add a static part to each `config.yaml` upon creation.

Maybe it's possible to hook into the site configuration creation process with a [PSR-14 event](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Events/EventDispatcher/Index.html). All code related to site configuration can be found here: `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Configuration/SiteConfiguration.php`. But I'm not that deep into that mechanism to tell if it's really possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand that but the advantage of the settings array is that it can be used as TS constants and in PageTS config, and that's what I need... But I will test the hook solution, thanks for the idea :)