Is there a way to extend SiteConfiguration settings.yaml
The documentation describes, how you can extended the site configuration config.yaml and enables you to edit the values in the backend: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ExtendingSiteConfig.html

Is there a way to also access the settings.yaml, which was introduced in TYPO3 v12.1?

Not now, planned for TYPO3 v13 AFAIK. Currently, you have to edit the file manually.

This seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407172/typo3-extending-site-configuration-gui-with-settings-and-imports

There is no GUI for the extracted site settings settings.yaml currently. As far as I know a GUI should be added at some points, but I don't have concrete implementation details or a schedule for it (or that someone is activly working on it).
In general, a new Settings API is a working area for TYPO3 v13 and additional Sets and other settings are already added for SiteConfiguration/Settings. Still file based first because if versionable
and deployment reasons. I don't know if a GUI is on the schedule
for v13 for Site Settings and the new Settings API or not. Based on the settings definition as a such the may be something comeing up at least for newer version.
The question was about access the settings. This is literally possible, as the Site model provides a getter to retrieve the settings object Site->getSettings(): SiteSettings  [1].
That means, if you have the site object or can retrieve it, you can access (read) the of that site, or example:
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteFinder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

$siteFinder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder:: class);
$site = $siteFinder->getSiteByPageId(123);
$siteSettings = $site->getSettings();

$siteSettings->has('key');
$allSettingsRelatedToRedirects = $siteSettings->get('redirects');


By "access" I meant extending the file, as is possible with `config.yaml'. Because the values defined in this file are easy to read from almost anywhere, I used it to replace settings you would have previously defined in Typoscript constants.  But what is missing is something like the constant editor to allow integrators and admins to change these values if needed.

Yeah - as said in my answer, that is a missing part. Some first steps with further thins has been done in v13 already and maybe there is comming more (like the constant editor vor the stuff / settings.yaml - at least for the things defined with the settings.definition.yaml) - we will see.

The file config/system/settings.php is the TYPO3 CMS 12 version of LocalConfiguration.php. This file can be edited in the backend via "Settings" > "Configure Installation-Wide Options".
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/Index.html

That's right, but I'm talking about settings.yaml.

Sorry. My mistake.
